# $\log f \left(e^{x}\right)$ is concave in $x$: what is this called?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is the following Condition $C$ standard, and if so, is there some standard terminology for it?

Function $f(x)$ (strictly) satisfies condition $C$ if
$$\log f \left(e^{x}\right)$$
is (strictly) concave in $x$.

Thanks!

EDIT: Well, I'm going to go with "$f\left(e^x\right)$ is log-concave." I think that's as close to a "standard" definition as I can get.